# Rename a group of files with one command

Tags: unix, bash

If I have a group of files with a .htm extention, how can I rename them all to .html?

```
mv *.htm *.html
```

does not work.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, `ren *.htm *.html` will work in Windows.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Or, you could use pure bash... (except for mv, that is..)

```
for file in *.htm; do mv "$file" "${file%.htm}.html"; done
```

and avoid the nasty basename stuff. ;)

Bash has an extensive set of variable expansion options. The one used here, '%', removes the smallest matching suffix from the value of the variable. The pattern is a glob pattern, so `${file%.*}` would also work. The '%%' operator removes the largest matching suffix, and is interchangeable in the example above, as the pattern is fixed, `${file%%.*}.html` would turn a.b.htm into a.html though.

See the variable substition section of the bash manpage for more neat tricks. There's a lot that can be done within bash directly.

Comment: Also note that these parameter expansions are not limited to *bash*. They are available on all Bourne-derived shells (*sh*, *ksh*, *bash*, *zsh*, *dash*, *ash*, etc.). The expansions are a part of [the POSIX specification for the “Shell Command Language”](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) and are highly portable.

Answer (score 12):

`rename(1)` is a Perl utility that does exactly what you want. In this case:

`rename 's/\.htm$/.html/' *htm`

or if you are using sub directories as well

*(requires Bash 4.0 and the globstar setting: `shopt -s globstar`)*

`rename 's/\.htm$/.html/' **/*htm`

Comment: rename is easier, but isn't a standard unix program; original question doesn't specify which unix.  Seems to be "prename" in some places.

Comment: `rename` comes with perl, and basically every unix comes with perl these days.

Comment: yes, but not every unix includes ancillary programs like 'rename' when they put perl on the system.  OSX, for instance, doesn't have "rename" on it.

Comment: @William: The double asterisk syntax is only available in Bash 4 and up and only if it's turned on with `shopt -s globstar` (off by default). Also, Linux and Unix have directories rather than folders.

Answer (score 12):

There shouldn't be spaces, newlines or other whitespace in the filenames, but this version of freiheit's answer handles those. It also uses `$()` instead of backticks for readability along with other benefits.

```
for file in *.htm
do
    mv "$file" "$(basename "$file" .htm).html"
done
```

Even better - for the special case of just adding on to the end:

```
for file in *.htm
do
    mv "$file" "${file}l"
done
```

Answer (score 7):

```
for file in *.htm; do
  mv $file `basename "$file" .htm`.html
done
```

Try it with an `echo` in front of the `mv` first time around.

The problem with your original is that "`mv *.htm *.html`" has the `*`s handled by the shell, so the `mv` command simply sees a list of all the .htm and .html files in the current directory. In other words, something like "`mv foo.htm bar.htm stuff.htm six.htm file.htm`".  mv only knows how to handle more than 2 arguments if the last one is a directory.

Comment: You should quote"$file", to handle spaces.

Comment: Your description of the original problem should be emphasised more strongly. This shell wildcard expansion behaviour is surprising and not intuitive for somebody coming from Windows land, and understanding what the shell does makes it clear why the original application of `mv` won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another pure bash example using string replace.

```
for file in *.htm; do mv $file ${file/htm/html}; done
```

Extra - this replaces all the occurrences of a string

```
for file in *.htm; do mv $file ${file//htm/html}; done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) you can use 'zmv'

Comment: zmv needs to be loaded first: `autoload zmv` then you can `zmv`

Comment: add `autoload zmv` to your `zsh` profile to have it available all the time

Answer (score 1):

The best tool is [mmv](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/mmv.html).

```
mmv \*.htm #1.html
```

Other examples of use (and of other tools) in "[GNU/Linux Command-Line Tools Summary](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/mass-rename.html)".

Comment: Your usage example fails. You need to escape `#`.

Comment: No, it works (I ALWAYS test before posting on SuperUser). The need to escape # depends on the shell you use (I use zsh).

Answer (score 0):

The *util-linux-ng* package (on Fedora) has a `rename` command similar to the one mentioned by [TRS-80](https://superuser.com/questions/8716/rename-a-group-of-files-with-one-command/8723#8723). You can use it like this:

```
rename .htm .html *.html
```