# Rename files in a directory

Tags: macos, unix, batch-rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rename a group of files with one command](https://superuser.com/questions/8716/rename-a-group-of-files-with-one-command)

I have a directory having `.txt` files. I need to rename the extension of all the files to `.xml`. How can I do this in command line?

I am using Mac OS X 10.7.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a terminal window and use this command:

```
for i in *.txt; do
    mv "$i" "${i%.*}.xml"
done
```

Comment: Breaks on files with spaces in their name. Also, `for ... ls *.txt` is extremely redundant. Could have been `for i in *.txt`, but that's not a safe way to iterate over files either.

Comment: @slhck: In what way is it unsafe?

Comment: @Scott: Please do not use `for i in \`ls\``. See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and #2.